# Emacs wanderlust IMAP password authentication

Tags: ssl, emacs, imap

In emacs/wanderlust, if one selects the 'clear' method of password transmission, but enables SSL for IMAP, is the password transmission secured by SSL encryption? Specifically, concern arises from the following para in the wanderlust Info manual:

> There are two ways to use SSL. One is to start SSL negotiation just
>   after the connection establishment (generic way). The other one is to
>   start SSL negotiation by invoking STARTTLS command in the each session.

So is password transmission done before or after SSL encryption in the first method? If before, then does the second (STARTTLS based) method ensure encrypted password transmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is secure in either case.

The difference between these methods is in another aspect:  The first method starts a TLS connection *right after* the TCP handshake, and *before* any IMAP exchange starts.  Hence, it uses a different port than regular IMAP, but can be used with IMAP servers that do not have built-in TLS support, by simply tunneling their traffic.

With the second method however, the client connects to the regular IMAP port and starts an unencrypted IMAP exchange.  However, before sending any credentials or any other private data it tells the server to upgrade the connection to a TLS connection, and only resumes the IMAP exchange (including password transfer) *after* this upgrade succeeded.  This method allows to serve encrypted IMAP from the default IMAP port, but needs an IMAP server that can handle this IMAP protocol extension.

Nowadays, most servers support STARTTLS, so both methods are mostly equivalent.  Use whatever Wanderlust uses as default.

Comment: STARTTLS is actually a syntax error after authentication.

Comment: Clear answer to my query. Thanks.